# JavaScript cleaner/purifier?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to cleanup JavaScript code?

I want to enable users to post arbitrary JS but i want to filter some of it out, like eval and document.write. Do you know of any tool that can do this?

Comment: What do you mean with filter out? Do you want to execute the user's code but stop some functions like the document.write?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter out risky functions like eval or document.write.

Comment: I don't get it... why filter `eval` if they can post arbitrary code anyway? Whatever you're trying to prevent by filtering out `eval`, `document.write`, etc., users _will_ be able to accomplish with workarounds. Example: `\u0065\u0076\u0061\u006c("alert (1234)")`

Comment: How can you filter/remove code without risking the code stops to work? It would make more sense to check for certain criteria and let the user know the post failed because they had code they are not allowed to.

Comment: @CalinDon Please update your question with what you've mentioned in these comments!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linter to filter some bad code out. A good linter is [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/).